# DXF ASCII to write multiple text strings

Tags: dxf

I can't seem to add multiple text strings to a DXF file. It works for when I only have a block of code for 1 line of text. I can't seem to add multiple lines.

I created the code shown below. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
 0
TEXT
  5
31
  8
0
  6
BYLAYER
 62
  256
 10
161.25
 20
120.25
 30
0
 40
1
  1
Sample Text 1
 50
0
 41
1
 51
0
  7

 71
    0
 11
161.25
 21
120.25
 31
0
210
0
220
0
230
1
 73
    3
0
TEXT
  5
31
  8
0
  6
BYLAYER
 62
  256
 10
100
 20
100
 30
0
 40
1
  1
Sample Text 2
 50
0
 41
1
 51
0
  7

 71
    0
 11
100
 21
100
 31
0
210
0
220
0
230
1
 73
    3
0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

The DXF file with the code shown above will not open in AutoCAD and/or Microstation. However it does open in LibreCAD which appears to be more forgiving with syntax.

I'd like it to open in AutoCAD AND Microstation. Any input would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handles (DXF group 5) should be unique within a file.

As such, you should not use the same handle for both text entities:

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
TEXT
  5
31  <----------+
               |
< ... >        |
               |
0              +----- Identical handles
TEXT           |
  5            |
31  <----------+
```

Comment: See: https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/group_codes_in_numerical_order_al_u05_c.htm